# Event handler for image load through jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, rendering

I am using jquery `$("selector").load("url")` method to load large markup from server. But in my case I have many large images inside that response html. And those images are rendering very slowly. So I would like to put a loading indicator until all images rendered completely. and then remove that indicator after all images are rendered completely. How can I achieve this using jquery `load` method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

one way is to load the indicater in `document.ready` and hide it in load callback function

```
$(function(){
  //show you loader indicator
  $('#indicator').show();
  $("selector").load("url",function(){
     //indicator hide 
     $('#indicator').hide();
 })
});
```

this is just an example to get you started...callback function of load is called when the load completes... you can however show the indicator whereever you need to..just hide it when the load completes.

Comment: I dont want to call on ready. I want to call it on click of some button. And also callback will be called once response comes, not everything(images) rendered completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.load` event attached with any DOM element like:

```
<div class="images" style="display:none;">
  <img src="img.png"/>
  <img src="img2.png"/>
  <img src="img3.png"/>
</div>
```

Now you can attach your actions in load event handler function:

```
$('.images img').load(function(){
   $('.images').show();
   //--Your code goes here //--
});
```

Comment: Callback will be called once response comes, not everything(images) rendered completely